# Replace Char in Switch Statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

The following is a code to replace vowels of a word with an underscore:

```
String[] vowelArray = arrayInput;
    for (int x = 0; x < vowelArray.length; x++){
        for (int a = 0; a < vowelArray[x].length(); a++){
            switch (vowelArray[x].charAt(x)){
                case 'A': vowelArray[x].charAt(x) = "_";
                case 'a': vowelArray[x].charAt(x) = "_";
                case 'E': vowelArray[x].charAt(x) = "_";
                case 'e': vowelArray[x].charAt(x) = "_";
                case 'I': vowelArray[x].charAt(x) = "_";
                case 'i': vowelArray[x].charAt(x) = "_";
                case 'O': vowelArray[x].charAt(x) = "_";
                case 'o': vowelArray[x].charAt(x) = "_";
                case 'U': vowelArray[x].charAt(x) = "_";
                case 'u': vowelArray[x].charAt(x) = "_";
                case 'Y': vowelArray[x].charAt(x) = "_";
                case 'y': vowelArray[x].charAt(x) = "_";
            }
        }
    }
```

However upon compilation, I receive this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:  The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

It occurs in the switch statement on each case.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't modify a `String` like that.  (At all, in fact.)

Comment: What do you suggest I do then?

Comment: You might want to add a `break;` statement after every case. Save yourself the exponential execution time.

Comment: Apply lvalue operand to the assignment operator in the statement.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel by the current code, it will be better to just have all the `case`s anidated and implement the last one (since all the paths do the same).

Comment: There are two problems: 1) Try to assign a value when calling method, which is wrong by default (thus the compiler error). 2) The way you're trying to update the `String` won't work since `String`s are immutable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't change a `String` in Java, it's an immutable object. What you *can* do, is getting the underlying `char[]` from the `String` , modifying the array, and creating a new `String` with it (and don't forget to end each `case` statement with a `break`):

```
String[] vowelArray = arrayInput;
for (int x = 0; x < vowelArray.length; x++) {
    char[] chars = vowelArray[x].toCharArray();
    for (int a = 0; a < chars.length; a++) {
        switch (chars[a]) {
            case 'A': chars[a] = "_"; break;
            case 'a': chars[a] = "_"; break;
            case 'E': chars[a] = "_"; break;
            case 'e': chars[a] = "_"; break;
            case 'I': chars[a] = "_"; break;
            case 'i': chars[a] = "_"; break;
            case 'O': chars[a] = "_"; break;
            case 'o': chars[a] = "_"; break;
            case 'U': chars[a] = "_"; break;
            case 'u': chars[a] = "_"; break;
            case 'Y': chars[a] = "_"; break;
            case 'y': chars[a] = "_"; break;
        }
    }
    vowelArray[x] = new String(chars);
}
```

Or even simpler, you could use the `replaceAll()` method to perform the substitution:

```
String[] vowelArray = arrayInput;
for (int x = 0; x < vowelArray.length; x++) {
    vowelArray[x] = vowelArray[x].replaceAll("[AaEeIiOoUuYy]", "_");
}
```

Comment: @ModifyYou you didn't copy the code _exactly_ as it is in my answer. Again, it's the same thing: strings are immutable, a method like `replaceAll()` doesn't modify the string, it returns a _new_ string that must be assigned somewhere, see my answer: I'm reassigning the array in the for loop

Comment: Yeah I saw my mistake and deleted it from the OP. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable, and what you're doing (`string.charAt(x) = "_";`) doesn't really make much sense. You are trying to assign a value to the result of a method invocation. The error message also describes the problem with your statement; the compiler is expecting a variable on the left-hand side.

To do what you want, you can use a regular expression with [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

```
String newString = string.replaceAll("[AEIOUYaeiouy]", "_");
```

You can even assign it back to the old string itself:

```
string = string.replaceAll("[AEIOUYaeiouy]", "_");
```

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of replaceAll. Thank you, and Oscar.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot change a String in Java, you can build a new string

```
 for (int x = 0; x < vowelArray.length; x++){
    StrinbBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (int a = 0; a < vowelArray[x].length(); a++){
        switch (vowelArray[x].charAt(a)){
            case 'A'://fall thru
            case 'a'://fall thru
            //and all the other case's
             b.append("_");
           break;
           default:
             b.append(vowelArray[x].charAt(a));
             break;
        }

    }
    vowelArray[x] = b.toString(); //replace the new string
}
```

Note that your `vowelArray[x].charAt(x)` should be `vowelArray[x].charAt(a)`

You can use another approach instead of a big switch as well:

```
String vowels = "AaEeIiOoUuYy";
if (vowels.indexOf(vowelArray[x].charAt(x)) != -1) {
   //it's a vowel
   b.append("_");
} else {
   b.append(vowelArray[x].charAt(x));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a `String` by changing one character.  There's no one method to return a new `String` with character `x` (i.e. `s.charAt(x)`) changed to `c`, but you can do it like this:

```
String newString = s.substring(0,x) + c + s.substring(x+1);
```

That is, characters of `s` from 0 to `x-1` inclusive; then the character `c`; then characters of `s` from `x+1` to the end.  This will work in the boundary cases (`x==0` or `x==s.length()-1`).  I'm posting this as a general solution for "what would you do instead of putting `charAt(x)` on the left side of an assignment", but the other answers are better for this particular problem.